# Не стартует Apache после обновления на Debian 8 Jessie

Tags: apache, debian

После обновления Debian 7 до Debian 8, при сохранении старого конфига, Apache2 не стартует, со следующей ошибкой.

> service apache2 start  * Starting web server apache2
>   *  * The apache2 configtest failed. Output of config test was: AH00526: Syntax error on line 89 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf: Invalid
>   command 'LockFile', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not
>   included in the server configuration Action 'configtest' failed.

Answer (score 3):

Открываем для редактирования конфиг апача:

> $ nano /etc/apache2/apache2.conf

находим строку:

> LockFile ${APACHE_LOCK_DIR}/accept.lock

И заменяем ее на :

> Mutex file:${APACHE_LOCK_DIR} default

Запускаем Apache2. 
Сервер должен запустится.